# How to run a some testsuites with concurrency and rest without concurrency using TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have 6 test suites out of which I would like to run 5 of them with 3 concurrent browsers and the remaining 1 without concurrency. Also, I would like to get 1 HTML file result of all the 6 test suites.

I have looked into the test runner but unable to figure out how do I run the 1 test suite without concurrency.

Here is the code from TestRunner:

```
let testcafe = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
  .then((tc) => {
    testcafe = tc;
    const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

    return runner
      .src('uitests/tests/test1.js', 'uitests/tests/test2.js', 'uitests/tests/test3.js', 'uitests/tests/tes4t.js', 'uitests/tests/test5.js')
      .browsers('chrome:headless')
      .screenshots('screenshots', true)
      .reporter('html', 'resultsrunner.html')
      .concurrency(3)
      .run({
        skipJsErrors: true,
      })
  })
  .then(() => {
    testcafe.close();
  });
```

What should I do to make my `test6.js` run without concurrency and append the results of all the 6 test suites in an HTML file?

````
      .src('uitests/tests/test6.js')
      .browsers('chrome:headless')
      .screenshots('screenshots', true)
      .reporter('html', 'resultsrunner.html')
      .run({
        skipJsErrors: true,
      })```
````

Comment: I don't know if this is possible within the 'createTestCafe' method.  As a side solution (thus why I'm not supplying a full answer) you could do 2 'createTestCafe' methods within the same file, output the results to 2 separate files, then within the file write code to open both files and append them together into 1 master file.

Comment: @TallKU - yeah I just tried and I have to create separate file for both kind of testsuites and run it from a shell script. But still I cannot get 1 html test result. I'm not sure that If I can get 1 html test result from these two separate run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testcafe does not support combining of tests with and without concurrency in one run. A slightly better approach than the one suggested by TallKU is to implement a [custom testcafe reporter](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/) and to use the same reporter's instance for two testcafe runs.